# How to look for exact matching word using Golang regexp?

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to find words in a large text file. The `MatchString` method doesn't inherently look for exact word match, rather it looks for the pattern as it should.

How does one check for exact word match using regexp package in Golang? I have tried some regex'es i found on SO, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/: "`\b` at ASCII word boundary (\w on one side and \W, \A, or \z on the other)"

Comment: so would the regex look like `\w<word>\W`?

Comment: No, `\bword\b`.

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't seem to work. https://play.golang.org/p/5WXIN3EEJRr

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: You missed some escaping: https://play.golang.org/p/-f0KEKb2EbF

Comment: Anyone finding this answer: if you *can* use strings Contains/HasPrefix/HasSuffix and speed is a problem then do so!  Even if multiple calls to strings methods are required this method is likely to be faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [zero-length word boundry sequence `\b`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/): https://play.golang.org/p/-f0KEKb2EbF

```
regexp.MatchString("\\bword\\b", test)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. Although when I am dynamically generating regexes using `fmt.Sprint`, it is not working. It worked when I hard coded all the words with in regex.

Comment: It's probably an issue with your escaping. Try printing out the result of your `Sprint` and make sure that the resulting string is the regex you want.

Comment: This does not match an exact word if the word is being followed by a ``-``. See: 
https://go.dev/play/p/QaIsGtIfHe5

Comment: @LearningPath your sample text uses the hyphenated word "News-try". Hyphen is not a word boundary. For use cases that require it to be treated as a word boundary, a different solution would be needed.

Comment: @Adrian that's why I posted that case, this is not an accurate "exact" match, you should be contemplating other options. The accepted answer only resolves around words which  ``\b`` maps to a boundary char inside regex, thus its not accurately  an exact match. If you want a really exact match, you should be doing ``^$`` line anchors.  As the title says, the user is asking an exact match with regex on GO.

Comment: @LearningPath actually as the title and question say, they are looking for exact *word* match, and specifically *not* looking for exact match, which they were already able to do when they posted the question. OP accepted the answer and commented that this solution does what they were asking for, so I'm not sure I understand the intent of your comments.j

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just exactly search for `word` string in a large file. You should be using line anchors (https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

You must use:

```
regexp.MatchString("(?sm)^word$", test)
```

The `(?sm)` flags enables the following:

- `s` as single-line (dotall)
- `m` for multi-line parsing

E.g. With the following list

```
word-
myword 
thiswordis
word2
aloja
_word_
.word
word
```

The pattern `regexp.MatchString("(?sm)^word$", test)` will only match the last `word` line.

If you use `\b` word boudary, you will match the first `word-` making this an inexact match.